# How write deserializer in json-binding (java ee 8) which transforms null values to " "?

Tags: java, jsonb, java-ee-8

What I should write in this method?

```
public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx, Type rtType) {
    while (parser.hasNext()) {

    }
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: You could annotate the properties that can be *null* with `@DefaultValue(" ") public String optionalMember;`.

Comment: This should work with all fields in all classes. If I use this annotation i will should write it in any classes. I think it is not good desicion.